# Bug free kernel version for Dell 7559? (skylake)

Tags: sound, kernel, dell, bluetooth, intel-graphics

I installed 16.04 on my Dell 7559 which has the following hardware:

- Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
- Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)

I started with kernel version 4.4.1 and it was a nightmare. If I let it go to sleep it would go into a soft lock and I would have to shut it down. Also the headphone jack doesn't output sound and the Bluetooth only works in non high fidelity mode. I installed 4.8.3 and it fixed the soft lock issue but the audio issues remain. I just wanted to see if anyone has found a kernel version where everything seems to work?

Comment: Your question might get closed soon. I would simply post a new question saying your audio only works in low resolution and asking how to get hi definition sound to work.

Comment: The bluetooth issue is being worked on due to bug reports being filed.  The developer says he will start working on it in a week after his vacation